# Tags in vowpal wabbit

Tags: tags, vowpalwabbit

I am doing binary classification using vowpal-wabbit. A particular record(set of features) has 10 zeroes and 5 ones. So, I am creating two lines in vowpal-format

```
-1 10 `50 |f f1
1 5 `50 |f f1
```

Since the prediction(probability) for both these records would be same, I want to keep the same tag, so that I can dedupe the predictions({tag,prediction}) later and join with my original raw-data. 
Is it possible to keep the same tag for more than one record in vowpal-wabbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First, the syntax above isn't correct**

To be identified as such, tags should either:

- Touch the `|` separator (no space between them) OR
- The leading quote, needs to be a simple quote, not a backquote, by convention.

(or both).

Otherwise you get:

    `` warning: `50 is not a good float, replacing with 0
    warning: `50 is not a good float, replacing with 0 ``

Which hints that `vw` interprets these "tags" as prediction-base.

For details, see [Input format in the official documentation](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format)

Once the example is fixed to the correct syntax:

`-1 10 '50|f f1
1 5 '50|f f1`

Which runs fine, we can answer the question:

> **Is it possible to keep the same tag for more than one record in vowpal-wabbit?**

Yes, you can.  The tag is merely a simple way to connect input and output (when predictions are involved), there's no check for uniqueness anywhere.  If you duplicate tags on input, you'll simply get the same duplicate tags on prediction output as well.

#### More notes:

- Even if two examples are identical, you may get different predictions, if the model has changed somewhat in between them. Remember `vw` is an online learner, so the model can continuously change with each example unless you add the `-t` (test-only, don't learn) option.
- Features whose value is zero are ignored, so you can drop them. The standard way in `vw` to say this is 'positive' and this is 'negative' is to use the values `{+1, -1}`. This is true for both labels and input features.

Comment: I think the syntax is correct [link](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial)
yes there should be simple quote. But tags don't need to touch |

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the answer: tags should either touch the `|` or use the  leading simple quote (or both), but if you do neither, it is the wrong syntax as you can see from the warning from `vw`.